# How can you pull values from a dictionary with a specific key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary that contains info in the following structure.

```
{
"name":"Isabella Romanazzi",
"screen_name":"bellaroma21",
"text":"RT @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No kids. Own apartment. Own car. Has a job. &amp; educated.",

"name":"xyzabc",
"screen_name":"xyzabc121",
"text":" Own car. Has a job. &amp; educated."
.
.
.
.

}
```

I am trying to retrieve all the values of the field with key 'text'.
This is the code I'm using currently

```
tweets={}
for item in json_dict:
    if "text" in json_dict:
        tweets[item]=json_dict['text']
print tweets
```

This is the output im getting. The code seems to be cycling through dict but only pulls the value of the first field repeatedly. What am I doing wrong?

> {u'contributors': u"RT @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No kids. Own
>   apartment. Own car. Has a job. & educated.", u'truncated': u"RT
>   @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No kids. Own apartment. Own car. Has a
>   job. & educated.", u'text': u"RT @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No
>   kids. Own apartment. Own car. Has a job. & educated.",
>   u'in_reply_to_status_id': u"RT @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No kids.
>   Own apartment. Own car. Has a job. & educated.", u'id': u"RT 
>   kids. Own apartment. Own car. Has a job. & educated.", u'user':
>   u"RT @fatNpretty: I'm 20 years old. No kids. Own apartment. Own car.
>   Has a job. & educated."}

Comment: Do you have a list of dictionaries? That cannot be one long dictionary, since you may not have non-unique keys within a dictionary.

Comment: Also, the code you use will add *every* key of `json_dict` to `tweets` as long `text` is a key in `json_dict` (and set every key's value to `json_dict['text']`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dict Comprehension for that.

```
>> dic = {'screen_name': 'xyzabc121', 'name': 'xyzabc', 'text': ' Own car. Has a job. &amp; educated.'}

>> {y for x,y in dic.items() if x.startswith("text")}
{' Own car. Has a job. &amp; educated.'}
```

Hope it helps.